# Laravel Job vs Event when creating a 3rd party api call

Tags: php, laravel

I want to know what is the best practice to make a 3rd party api call in `Laravel`.

- Create a Job that makes the API call in handle() function and then use `Job::dispatch()` to actually call it from the controller.
- Create an Event that has the API call in its listener, and use `Event::fire()` from the controller.
- Or create an Event and Job both where Job has the API call, Event dispatches the job and the event itself is fired from the controller.

**I want the job to be non-blocking so that my controller code does not block when job is dispatched or event is fired.**

What is the best practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They usually cross over each other, in simpler terms Jobs can be referred as **proactive** and events can be referred as reactive. It depends on you how you want to your system. Most developer create jobs in events. Another point I saw recently most programmer use services for business logic. Services are nothing just normal classes resides in separate folder(mostly named as service) that contain business logic. Controller are only used for IO operations. Even validation is separated these days.

Comment: I used crossover, means created Job in Event. Used `Event::fire()` in controller and `Job::dispatch()` in event. **But the controller is still blocking.**, means if I place a sleep(10) inside the job, my browser hangs for 10 seconds while it should not.

Comment: Found the solution to make it non-blocking, the queue configuration should use something other than `sync` as queue driver. This SO answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39006287/how-to-avoid-waiting-for-the-laravel-queue-and-continue-with-functionality) helped a lot.